# Why does this script output corrupt files when run automatically with crontab?

Tags: bash, shell-script, fedora, cron

I have a script that scans a folder for all .mp3 files and creates an index.
Next it waits 5s otherwise it doesn't work correctly. 
Lastly, it removes bad characters from the song names.

I have this running automatically with sudo crontab:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Creates index file.
find /var/www/html/uploads/Music/ -name '*.mp3' > /var/www/html/uploads/Music/songs.index | sleep 5s | sudo sed -i -e 's/\/var\/www\/html/\.\./g' /var/www/html/uploads/Music/songs.index
```

For some reason when it's run through crontab it creates a file that has to be converted to text and back to an index in order to read it. When you run the same script manually it works fine. What am I missing?

crontab file:

```
1 * * * * /home/aaeadmin/bin/midnightRun.bash
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is *likely* because you run the commands in a pipeline.

Each part of a pipeline is started at the same time and run concurrently with the other parts of the same pipeline.  This means that the `find` command starts at exactly the same time as the `sed` command.  It is only data passed through the pipeline, from the standard output of one command into the standard input of the next, that synchronises the different commands.

Also note that you don't actually *use* the pipeline aspect of the pipeline.  There is no data being passed between the commands.

Your script would be better written as

```
#!/bin/bash
#Creates index file.

find /var/www/html/uploads/Music/ -name '*.mp3' > /var/www/html/uploads/Music/songs.index

sed -i -e 's/\/var\/www\/html/\.\./g' /var/www/html/uploads/Music/songs.index
```

Here, the `find` command would finish executing before the `sed` command started.  I have also removed the `sudo` command as it is clearly not needed (if `find` can write into the file, then `sed` can read and modify it without `sudo`).

If you find that you *do* need `sudo` to write `songs.index`, I would suggest that you instead run this cron job in the crontab belonging to a user with permissions to write to the target directory `/var/www/html/uploads/Music`.

A pipelined solution would be

```
#!/bin/sh
#Creates index file.

find /var/www/html/uploads/Music/ -name '*.mp3' |    
sed -e 's,^/var/www/html,..,' >/var/www/html/uploads/Music/songs.index
```

Here, `find` writes *directly* to the `sed` command, and the result of the `sed` command is written to the index file. The communication of data (pathnames) from `find` into `sed` keeps the two processes synchronised and `sed` would *wait* for `find` to produce the next line of input before continuing (and vice versa; `find` would wait for `sed` to process the data before trying to output more data).

I've also made the `sed` command easier to read and I've anchored the regular expression to the start of the line and removed the unnecessary `g` flag at the end. Since it now reads from the `find` command, I've also removed the `-i` option (strictly speaking, the `-e` option could also be removed).

Another thing I've changed is the `#!` line.  You're not using any `bash`-specific features, so we may as well run the script with a (possibly) more light-weight shell.

If you want to write the filenames of the found files to the index, with the initial `/var/www/html` replaced by `..` you could also do that directly from `find`:

```
#!/bin/sh
#Creates index file.

find /var/www/html/uploads/Music/ -type f -name '*.mp3' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        printf "../%s\n" "${pathname#/var/www/html/}"
    done' sh {} + >/var/www/html/uploads/Music/songs.index
```

This single `find` command would find the pathnames all regular files (i.e. not directories etc.) whose names matched the given pattern.  For batches of these pathnames, a short inline shell script is called.  The script simply iterates over the current batch of pathnames and prints them out slightly modified.

The modification to the pathname is done through the parameter substitution `${pathname#/var/www/html/}`.  This *removes* the string `/var/www/html/` from the start of the value in `$pathname`.  The `printf` format string used would then ensure that this part is replaced by `../`.

See also

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough explanation.

Comment: @Kusalananda tnx, then why as OP says it works fine running manually?

Comment: using find ... -exec sh -c 'process file' in this way will start a child process for every file. pipe the output of find to sed; for example: find /tmp -exec sh -c 'echo "pid: ", $$' \;

Comment: @user174174 It _may_ work depending on timing issues between the `find` and `sed` processes. It basically comes down to luck.

Comment: @ChuckCottrill Note that I'm using `-exec sh -c ... {} +`. This will call `sh -c` with as large batches of files as possible, in a _similar_ way as `xargs` would do. It would not start one `sh -c` process per found file.  It's the `+` at the end (rather than `\;`) that makes the difference. Also see the link at the end of the answer.